# Display an item from a list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I have a sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/cristian-marius/pen/LYPabxe)

I want the item with the `"item-extra"` class to be randomly displayed in the item list.

Now, the code rearranges all the elements.

I want the rest to remain fixed and only the one with the `"item-extra`" class will be moved to each page reload.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

```css
.item-extra {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li class="item-extra">item extra</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the .insertBefore() function.

Example:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var itemExtra = document.querySelector('.item-extra');
var ulLength = ul.children.length;

ul.insertBefore(itemExtra, ul.children[Math.random() * ulLength | 0]);
```

```css
.item-extra {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li class="item-extra">item extra</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is a very good solution,
I have only one question, can you please explain to me what the code below means?
especially "| 0"
[Math.random () * ulLength | 0]

Comment: @Cristi This returns you a random number between 0 and the amount of childrens your ul has. The `| 0` at the end gets rid of the decimals.

Comment: Ah, Instead of Math.floor()